# Finding element in dynamic path to remove from JSON

Tags: python, json

If you have some JSON that will contain an unknown path to something like

```json
...... {
                        "in": "query",
                        "name": "@baseType",
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "To route object models\nValues: \xxx\uyyy or \xxx\zzzd"
                    },
                    {
                        "in": "header",
                        "name": "X-System",
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "Inventory: Inventory\\nFor Quickconnect: My Resourse"
                    },
                    {
                        "in": "header",
                        "name": "env",
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "Environment, i.e: a01, b02, etc."
                    }
```

I need to delete all the default lines where `"in": "header"`

but in my case, I have no idea all the paths that could happen. Any ideas?

If I know the path, then this is relatively easy.

```py
for get_param_rec in api_spec['paths']['/resource']['get']['parameters']:
            if get_param_rec['in'] == "header" and "default" in get_param_rec:
                logger.info("      found bad header record and deleting it.")
                del get_param_rec['default']
```

Comment: As JSON is always a tree, if there's absolutely no prior knowledge of it, you can walk it recursively. `type()` can tell you if something is a list or a dict, like if you type `type([]) is list` or `type({}) is dict`, it will display `True` for both. However it may be worth mentioning that being able to do something doesn't immediately make it a good idea, if the data structure is completely arbitrary, similar problems will arise at every single task related to it.

Comment: one way to do this would be to load the json as a text file (pretty print) and just remove all of those mentions of `"in": "header"`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the JSON dictionary with a recursive function:

```py
import json


def remove_default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        if obj.get('in') == 'header':
            print('found bad header record and deleting it.')
            obj.pop('default', None)
        for v in obj.values():
            remove_default(v)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for v in obj:
            remove_default(v)


with open('input.json') as f:
    obj = json.load(f)

remove_default(obj)
print(json.dumps(obj, indent=2))
```

`input.json`:

```json
{
  "inner1": {
    "inner2": [
      {
        "in": "query",
        "name": "@baseType",
        "type": "string",
        "description": "To route object models",
        "default": "keep it"
      },
      {
        "in": "header",
        "name": "X-System",
        "type": "string",
        "default": "Inventory: Inventory"
      },
      {
        "in": "header",
        "name": "env",
        "type": "string",
        "default": "Environment, i.e: a01, b02, etc."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`output`:

```bash
found bad header record and deleting it.
found bad header record and deleting it.
```

```json
{
  "inner1": {
    "inner2": [
      {
        "in": "query",
        "name": "@baseType",
        "type": "string",
        "description": "To route object models",
        "default": "keep it"
      },
      {
        "in": "header",
        "name": "X-System",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "in": "header",
        "name": "env",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Dicts are meant to be looked up by keys. You should not need to iterate through a dict to set a flag when `if k == 'in' and v == 'header'` is true. Do `if obj['in'] == 'header'` directly instead.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. The iteration is not needed. I use `obj.get('in')` instead of your suggestion `obj['in']` to avoid `KeyError` exception when the key is not there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function that removes bad records according to your criteria at each depth level. Normalize each sub-dict to a sequence of values so you can iterate through its sub-records in the same way as a sub-list:

```
def remove_bad_records(obj):
    values = ()
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        if obj['in'] == 'header':
            obj.pop('default', None)
        values = obj.values()
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        values = obj
    for value in values:
        remove_bad_records(value)
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/DefensiveMadeupService